# How do I lock matplotlib window resizing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on an open source project that involves mouse interaction (via *mpl_connect*) with a scatter plot using pyplot in **matplotlib**. I was able to disable the bottom toolbar from appearing with:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
```

But I haven't found anything similar for locking the width/height of the window and disabling resizing. (Currently, the clickable areas are calculated on startup and do not change if the window is resized.) Is there a way to disable resizing for now until I implement a version that allows resizing without breaking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib supports several backends. To see what backend you're using (I have `TkAgg`):

```
>>> pyplot.get_backend()
u'TkAgg'
```

Backend can be one of `GTKAgg`, `GTK3Agg`, `GTK`, `GTKCairo`, `GTK3Cairo`, `WXAgg`, `WX`, `TkAgg`, `Qt4Agg`, `Qt5Agg`, `macosx` (see http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend).

With a `TkAgg` backend you can prevent a window from resizing in width and height using  `resizable(False, False)` (http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

bck = pyplot.get_backend()
print "Backend is " + bck
mng = pyplot.get_current_fig_manager()
if (bck == "TkAgg"):   
    mng.window.resizable(False, False)
elif (bck == "QT4Agg"):
    print "See previous answer"
else:
    print "?"
```

If you have the required packages installed you can switch backends using for instance

```
>>> pyplot.switch_backend('QT4Agg')
```

Comment: I was using TkAgg and this solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a backend-independent way to do that, but there are various backend-specific solutions. For example, for the Qt backend you could use [`QWidget.setFixedSize`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setFixedSize):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
win = fig.canvas.window()
win.setFixedSize(win.size())

plt.show()
```

To fix the size of the canvas drawing area rather than the whole window you could use `fig.canvas.setFixedSize` instead.